# Finding out the hosts blocked by mysql server

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me how to list the hosts which are blocked by the mysql server due to the reason that they crossed the limit of max_connect_errors. Is there any table in which MySQL server keeps this data. I am using mysql-server-5.1.63

Answer (score 3):

Noted in 5.6.5 changelog.

MySQL now provides improved access to the host cache, which contains
client host name and IP address information and is used to avoid DNS
lookups. These improvements have been implemented:

- A host_cache Performance Schema table exposes the contents of the
  host cache so that it can be examined using SELECT statements. The
  Performance Schema must be enabled or this table is empty.

  If you upgrade to this release of MySQL from an earlier version, you
  must run mysql_upgrade (and restart the server) to incorporate this
  change into the performance_schema database.
- The cache size is configurable using the host_cache_size system
  variable. Setting the size to 0 disables the host cache.This is
  similar to starting the server with --skip-host-cache, but
  host_cache_size is more flexible because it can also be used to
  resize, enable, or disable the host cache at runtime, not just at
  server startup. If you start the server with --skip-host-cache to
  disable the host cache, it cannot be re-enabled at runtime.
- There are Connection_errors_xxx status variables that provide
  information about the nature of connection errors and that can help
  diagnose connection problems.

Improved access to host cache contents makes it possible to answer
questions such as how many hosts are cached, or how close hosts are
to being blocked (by checking whether the
host_cache.SUM_CONNECT_ERRORS column is approaching the value of the
max_connect_errors system variable).

Comment: This is only applicable for MySQL 5.6.  There does not appear to be a way to access this information in prior versions.